# MySQL Complex Join Optimization

Tags: mysql

I have a result set that I obtain from the join between three tables using:

```
SELECT X.*, Y.Name FROM `A` AS X
INNER JOIN `B` AS Y
INNER JOIN `C` AS Z
ON X.id=Y.id AND X.categoryID=Z.categoryID
WHERE X.userID_FK=%d AND X.listID_FK=%d 
ORDER BY Z.categoryRank ASC
```

I have a fourth table 'D' which contains:

```
-------------------------------
  id_FK    userID_FK    vote
-------------------------------
```

Here `(id_FK, userID_FK)` pair is a PK.

Each `X.id` returned by the first query could have multiple entries in the `D` table. Normally, for each returned row, in order to count votes per `id`, I'd write a query like:

```
SELECT SUM(vote) FROM D WHERE `id`=%d
```

I am wondering if I could optimize these two queries into a single query as the current scheme results in `O(n)` execution time. `n` being the number of results returned by the first query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it like this

```
SELECT
X.*,
Y.Name,
(SELECT
   SUM(vote)
   FROM D
   WHERE `id` = X.id) as Count
FROM `A` AS X
INNER JOIN `B` AS Y
INNER JOIN `C` AS Z
ON X.id = Y.id
  AND X.categoryID = Z.categoryID
WHERE X.userID_FK =  % d
AND X.listID_FK =  % d
ORDER BY Z.categoryRank ASC
```